# How to monitor Project creation using GCP Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I(GCP admin user) have a GCP organization called `example.com` and I want to monitor whenever there is a GCP project being created by some user in the organization.

So I created a GCP `Project A` and go to Stackdriver Loggin page to search for logs. But all the log entries I can find are limited to `Project A`. Like below

```
Resource Manager CreateProject admin@example.com .....
```

But I also want to find `Project B` created by user B and `Project C` created by user C.

I am not sure where to set what  permissions to view `CreateProject` logs across all the projects.

Comment: Is the project part of an organization?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes Project A , Project B, Project C are all in the same organization.

Comment: Have a look at the GCP Dashboard tab Activity https://medium.com/google-cloud/gcp-dashboard-overview-c80ffd0ed521 and Audit logs https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit. In addition check Logs Viewer (Preview) https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-preview#logs_viewer_preview_existing_and_upcoming_features - it has feature "View organization and folder level logs". Please let me know which one more suitable for your use case.

Comment: Do you know in advance names of new projects and when they were created?